# CLion Build Configuration: How do I set LDFLAGS?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I want to set `CC`, `CXX`, and `LDFLAGS`. I typically compile and run this project through the command line, but I'd like to develop using an IDE so I am now trying to use CLion. In "Build, Execution, and Deployment" in the preferences menu, I have the CC and CXX variables passed using CMake Options as seen in the attached picture. However, I'm not sure how to set `LDFLAGS` (there is are multiple cmake options for linkers). If this is my `LDFLAGS` how would I pass them? I don't want to modify the CMakeLists.txt file since these values are not universal for all systems...

```
-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `CMakeLists.txt` file for your project. You will find it in the project explorer, at the root level of your project.

In order to change the linker flags you then have several options.

To set **global** linker flags for all targets in your project, you can set one of the following:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "xxx")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "xxx")     
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "<your flags here>")
```

If you want to set the linker flags for **just one target**, then you can use [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html)

```
set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "<your flags here>")
set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "<your flags here>")
set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "<your flags here>")
```

[This link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmakelists-file.html) has an introduction to working with cmake in CLion.

Note also that `_DEBUG` and `_RELEASE` aren't the only configuration types, there are also `_MINSIZEREL` and `_RELWITHDEBINFO`

Comment: Variables `CMAKE_*_LINKER_FLAGS*` can be passed to cmake too (via -D options). So no needs to change `CMakeLists.txt` for that purpose.

Comment: So would I pass the following? `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib`

Comment: If it's only temporary yes, if it's something you want permanently, then I'd suggest editing your cmakelists